# Does ppoll aggregate packets?

Tags: sockets, polling, epoll, packets

Does `ppoll()` aggregate packets?  I have a socket library I built that works great with low throughput.  However when I start to increase the number of messages i begin to see packet size increases.  I checked the sender size and all the packets the sender sends are correct.  When the `recv()` fucntion is called the packets begin to max out and causes the app to fault.  Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ppoll()` doesn't aggregate packets, but the socket receive buffer does, and so does the socket send buffer at the sender. You cannot rely on receive counts in TCP: there are no messages, and boundaries between writes at the sender are not preserved at the receiver. It is strictly a byte-stream. Any packetization is entirely up to you to implement.

> When the recv() fucntion is called the packets begin to max out and causes the app to fault.

Only if you have a bug in your code. Typical errors include:

- assuming that `recv()` did or didn't fill the buffer
- sticking a null at the end of the buffer to null-terminate it for string handling, which won't work if the buffer was filled
- assuming there wasn't an error, or wasn't end of stream
- ignoring the count returned by `recv()` altogether.